# Laravel - Keep watching Table Column

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I am creating an application and when the user registers the value 0 is assigned to the `role` column, however as it will using the application, this value can be changed. Is there any method of watching the change of that column? I would like to send an email to the user if this value change to 1.

Comment: Some code changes the value, right? So send the email from there, or throw an event and listen for that event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two possible ways.

## 1 Use a ModelObserver.

Using a ModelObserver you can "listen" to the saving or updating events. They are called before the action is executed and you can send or queue an e-mail from that method.

[Model Observer documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#model-observers)

## 2 Use a mutator

You can use a function who will intercept a change in a model property.

[Mutators documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators)

I hope it helps.

Comment: Cool! This seen to be an alternative! Will try it later!